# Specify a custom program for handling a protocol

Tags: ftp, protocol

I want to associate the FTP protocol to Filezilla. I click on

1. Control Panel
2. Control Panel Home
3. Default Programs
4. Set Associations

Then I select the FTP protocol and click on *Change program...* but I can specify just *Chrome*, *Internet Explorer* and *Firefox*.

Is it possible to add *Filezilla* to this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it through the registry:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx

Here is a little utility that makes it a bit easier:

http://customurl.codeplex.com/

Comment: Great!!!!!!!!!!!